# Some java errors that I can't understand

Tags: java, compiler-errors, minecraft

So I am learning to make Minecraft Plugins. When I type `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(listener: this, plugin:  this);`, I get some errors. I will provide a screenshot of how it looks. But first, here is my code:

```
package me.eventplugin.eventsplugin;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerBedLeaveEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class EventsPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        System.out.println("The plugin will now startup");
        // This is the code that gives me errors
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(listener: this, plugin:  this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onLeaveBed(PlayerBedLeaveEvent event){
        // Here is the code that will run once the event is triggered
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        player.sendMessage("Good Morning!!!");
    }

}
```

The instructor guy had typed the same thing I did, but I have the error, and he doesn't. Here is the screenshot: [image: The error image]

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `listener: this, plugin:  this` isn't valid Java. Remove the `listener:` and `plugin:`.

Comment: @AndyTurner ok and what to replace it with?

Comment: Seems like you've copied this from somewhere. *@AndyTurner ok and what to replace it with?* - depends on what you want to do.

Comment: _ok and what to replace it with?_ Nothing - the `listener:` and `plugin:` are displayed by the IDE to give you a hint about the parameters names used in the function.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks it works too

Comment: To clarify, you should replace it with `.registerEvents(this, this);`. `listener:` and `plugin:` were inserted by the IDE for clarity, but are not actually part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't use named arguments, but positional arguments. I.e, the first argument in `registerEvents` is the listener and the second is the plugin. Remove the labels and you should be fine:

```java
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

Comment: AHHHHH i get it now thanks a lot